# Error empty content gmail using javamail api send email smtp

Tags: email, gmail, jakarta-mail, html-email

I'm working project : jsf, richfaces. I has just updated javamail api newest version 1.5.5 at https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home
When i test send email from gmail to my gmail, 
Subject : **Subject test**.
Content : **Content test**. And config : **smtp.gmail.com**, **465**, **SSL**.
It has just subject and **no content** in my inbox receive gmail :

[image]

And log :

[image]

And my code :

```
           try {
                MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
                sf.setTrustAllHosts(true); 
                final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
                // Set the host smtp address
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", SMTP_PORT);
                props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
                props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            .......
            .......
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            session.setDebug(true);
            // create a message
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setText("UTF8");
            // set the from and to address
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(SMTP_AUTH_USER);
            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
            System.out.println(addressFrom);
            msg.setSubject(subject, "utf-8");
            ......
            ......
                try {
                    String content = replaceCharacterInEmail(cus, null,null, message);

                    MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
                    mbp1.setContent(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                    // attach the file to the message
                    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
                    int count = 0;
                    if(files != null){
                        while (count < files.size()) {
                            MimeBodyPart mbdp = new MimeBodyPart();
                            mbdp.attachFile(files.get(count));
                            mp.addBodyPart(mbdp);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    // create the Multipart and add its parts to it
                    mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
                    // add the Multipart to the message
                    msg.setContent(mp);
                    Transport.send(msg);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    invalidAddress += (", " + address.trim());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    if (!"".equals(emailFails)) {
                        emailFails = emailFails.substring(1);
                    }
                }
```

But, when i test above code at another project test (java application) with above lib javamail. It's ok :
[image].

I don't think problem at version of lib javamail. I don't know different between 2 project, because part send email is similar. How can i fix that error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please observe this email structure:
-- multipart/mixed
  -- mutlipart/alternative
    -- text/plain
    -- text/html
  -- application/octet-stream (or any other mimetypes)

Comment: Sorry for my question is not clear. I found problem is conflict library at lib of jboss server and lib of app.ear (deploy).

Answer (score 0):

I found problem is conflict library at lib of jboss server and lib of app.ear (deploy).

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Note that you should be able to get rid of **all** the socket factory properties and variables in your program; you shouldn't need any of them.